# ActionView::Template::Error (can't dup Symbol): -- Issue with AWS only in case of quality decrease for image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I was doing some image optimization on my site. Things are working awesome on development machine but in production mode I am getting an error ie:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (can't dup Symbol):
```

**This is happening only in case of aws, If I remove this then things working perfectly fine:**

A code I was using and was working perfectly:

```
  has_attached_file :attachment, {
             :styles => { 
                 :medium=>"654x346>",
                 :small => "260x400>",
                 :thumb => "75x75#",
                 :facebook_meta_tag => "200x200#" 
                 }, :include_updated_timestamp => false
             }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

But now I modified this and Its working perfectly fine in development environment but not working on production environment.

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
   :styles => {
     :medium => {
       :geometry => "654x346>",
       :quality => 60,
       :format => 'JPG'
     },
     :small => {
       :geometry => "260x400>",
       :quality => 60,
       :format => 'JPG'
     },
     :thumb => {
       :geometry =>"75x75#",
       :quality => 60,
       :format => 'JPG'
     },
     :facebook_meta_tag => {
       :geometry =>"200x200#",
       :quality => 50,
       :format => 'JPG'
     }
     }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

Other relevant settings:

```
 PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {
      :storage => :s3, 
      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/amazons3.yml",
}
```

amazons3.yml

```
production:
   access_key_id: XXXXxxxXXXXxxx
   secret_access_key: XXXXxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxxXXXXxxx
   bucket: images.XXXXxxx.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
  has_attached_file :attachment, {
       :styles => {
         :medium => ["654x346>", :jpg],
         :small => ["260x400>", :jpg], 
         :thumb => ["75x75#", :jpg],
         :facebook_meta_tag =>["200x200#", :jpg] 
         }, 
          :convert_options => {
             :medium => "-quality 60",
             :small => "-quality 60",
             :thumb => "-quality 60",
             :facebook_meta_tag => "-quality 60" 
             } 
          }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
```

Answer (score -1):

`ActionView::Template::Error` tends to be an error raised inside of a view (Rails re-wraps errors inside views inside `ActionView::Template::Error exceptions`).

To help you more I'd need to see the backtrace and the view involved.

This is not really an answer, but if this helps you find the cause you may as well accept it.